# Take AVG from SQL Table AND Display in HTML

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

I looked up this answer in numerous forums and none seem to solve my problem. I am looking for a bit of help.

**I want to take the average of numbers in a SQL database and display the average in HTML. I am using Flask, Python, SQL, and HTML.**

***Here is my PYTHON code:***

```
avg_hours = db.execute("SELECT CAST(AVG(hours) AS int) FROM pain WHERE user_id = ?", user_id)
```

**My HTML code:**

```
      {% for row in avg_hours %}
         <h4>Average Hours: {{ row }}   </h4>
       {% endfor %}
```

***But it displays like this on the html page:***

```
Average Hours: {'CAST(AVG(hours) AS int)': 11}
```

***How do I get it to display just the number? I want the display to show***

```
Average Hours : 11
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

*I figured it out. Here is the solution for others who may run into the problem:*

**Python Code:**

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio"""
    user_id = session["user_id"]

    #average of numbers in the column hours from the table pain for user
    avg_hours = db.execute("SELECT AVG(hours) AS average FROM pain WHERE user_id = ?", user_id)

    #i is the row in the avg_hours database
    for i in avg_hours:
       #create a variable for the average
       average1 = i["average"]
       #create new variable to convert value into an integer 
       average2 = int(average1)

 #render template to display value on html page
 return render_template("index.html", average=average2)
```

Simple HTML Code:

```
     <h4>Average Hours: {{ average }}   </h4>
```